Book series set in the future on a spaceship
In the late 90s when I was in secondary school I read a series of books, potentially 3. They were set in the future and the story was set on a spaceship. The characters had genetic memories of modern Earth, but some were born on Mars. The ship had genetic material on board of animals from Earth that had now gone extinct.

DV not mine, but I think they want more information

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

@Rohit - The genetic memory thing seems quite identifying

Was it a generation ship? Meaning it would take generations to reach the destination star system? Were the people asleep or living their lives on the ship?

@tgrignon - The OP states some of the people were born on Mars, so probably not a generation ship.
